# Nodemon is not working as dev dependencies

Tags: npm, backend, nodemon

I am working on a project of nodejs and I need to install nodejs. I want to install nodemon as dev dependencies, hence I've entered `npm i -D nodemon`. the command install nodemon and it is visible in dev dependencies as well but when I enter nodemon -v it shows

*The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*

What can I do ?

Comment: Try using this command to check the version of any type of dependency installed: `npm list nodemon`

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed it only in your project and not globally, you need to put the call to `nodemon` in an npm script (e.g. `dev`) and run that instead.

In your `package.json`, you would have an entry `"dev": "nodemon"` under `scripts` and then use `npm run dev`. For the equivalent of `nodemon -v` you'd use `npm run dev -- -v`.

Alternatively you can also use `npx nodemon` or `./node_modules/.bin/nodemon`, but the script way is usually preferred because it also documents what exact command you'd use for your dev server (you can add arguments in the script as well).

Answer (score 0):

### Why it happened

When you installed `npm i -D nodemon` you installed it in the scope of your project. That means that it is accessible through the scripts in `package.json`. But when you input in your terminal `nodemon run dev`, it isn't recognized since it isn't installed globally on your PC.

### Solutions

a) Install globally:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

b) Run from the scripts of your `package.json`. For example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

and then in your terminal"

```
npm run dev
```